# Could not withdraw tokens after crowd sale

Tags: tokens, crowdsale

I'm trying to implement smart contract for crowd sale and faced following problem.

Firstly, I created test token [here](https://gist.github.com/Gim6626/6f7505b8447dc72a071359b5948dbaae)  on Ethereum- using examples from OpenZeppelin framework and test CrowdSale contract using example from ethereum.org/crowdsale, source code follows. Then in Rinkeby test network:

1. Deployed token contract
2. Deployed token sale contract with target equals 1 ether, duration 10 minutes with link to my test token as reward token
3. From two test accounts transfered 0.4 and 0.6 ether to token sale contract
4. From main account send 500 tokens to crowd sale account
5. From contract creator account after crowdsale withdrawed using function safeWithdrawal 0.6 + 0.4 = 1 ether
6. From test two account tried to withdraw tokens but get error as on screenshot - "It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume all the gas you provide".

[image: Token wihdrawal error]

Could anybody help me to find to fix it?

P.S.: Here is source code of crowd sale contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract token { function transfer(address, uint256){  } }

contract DVFooCrowdsale5 {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    // uint public price;
    uint tokensForSale;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    /* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function DVFooCrowdsale5(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        // uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        uint tokensForSaleCount,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        // price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokensForSale = tokensForSaleCount;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () payable {
        assert(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        //tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        uint256 amount;
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
        else if (fundingGoalReached)
        {
            amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            uint256 toSend = 1 ether * amount / amountRaised * tokensForSale;
            tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, toSend);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It tells you the error.. you have not sent enough gas.

Comment: @ThomasClowes, I tried to send enough gas with this transaction, still no tokens.

Comment: Both contributors accounts raise the same error? Is tokenReward set correctly? Out of gas condition also can mean some conditions of your contract are not correct, and it is throwing an exception.

Comment: @Ismael, yes, both contributors see the same error. Rechecked tokenReward several times. What exact conditions of contract throws an exception I could not find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was in '1 ether' multiplier in safeWithdrawal.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by the '1 ether' multiplier?
Thanks!